# What is the correct way to `push` a updated model back to store?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-model

I am trying to `push` the updated `model` back to `store`. i tried with couple of ways still getting failed.

Please help me to understand to push the `model` back to store without updating `backend` api.

here is my try:

```
    import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function(params) {

        if(this.store.hasRecordForId('card-list', params.id)){
            return this.store.peekRecord('card-list', params.id );
        }
      },
      actions:{
        formValidateBeforeNext:function(){

            var model = this.controllerFor(this.routeName).get('model');

            var modelId = this.controllerFor(this.routeName).get('model').get("id");
            var oneTimeFee = this.controllerFor(this.routeName).get('model').get("oneTimeFee");
            var monthlyInstalmentAmount = this.controllerFor(this.routeName).get('model').get("monthlyInstalmentAmount");


            var updatedModel = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(model));

            updatedModel.type="card-list";
            updatedModel.id="13";

            console.log( "model would be:-" , updatedModel );
    //sending just a updated model fails
            let itemModel = this.store.push({'card-list': model  });
//after stringfy trying to update still fails
            let itemModel = this.store.push({'data': updatedModel  });



            // this.store.pushObject(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(model)));

            console.log( "store data", this.store.peekRecord('card-list', modelId ) )

            this.transitionTo('cs2i.balance.balanceReview', {id:modelId});

        }
      }
    });
```

What is wrong here? what is the correct way to put back the mode with updates?

**UPDATE:Error added**

```
Expected an object in the 'data' property in a call to 'push' for undefined, but was instance
Error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push` method will expect the data in the expected format. for eg, if you are using the JSONAPI. the below is the expected one.

```
store.push({
  data: {
    // primary data for single record of type `Person`
    id: '1',
    type: 'person',
    attributes: {
      firstName: 'Daniel',
      lastName: 'Kmak'
    }
  }
});
```

You can convert json payload into the expected form by doing so,

```
store.push(store.normalize('person', data));
```

If you are having raw JSON data, then you can try `pushPayload`.

```
this.get('store').pushPayload('card-list',data);
```

Refer [EmberData Model Maker](http://andycrum.github.io/ember-data-model-maker/) to know expected result format.

Read ember guides [models/pushing-records-into-the-store](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/models/pushing-records-into-the-store/)
Read [push API doc](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.Store/methods/pushPayload?anchor=push)
Read [pushPayload doc](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.Store/methods/pushPayload?anchor=pushPayload) -

Comment: Just ensure the `updatedModel ` this is in the expected format.

Comment: sure will try and get back to you. when i push the `model` still `id` need to added manually?

Comment: Yes. store is like data base in client side, it requires id to identify the record uniquely.

Comment: No problem.if it's already exists then it will update the record. if not it will add new record

Comment: Very thanks to you. it works. Please don't stop to help other too.. we have very less resource to get help like you!!! really great!.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151673/discussion-between-user2024080-and-kumkanillam).

Comment: I doing transition to next page it works. but the loaded page not calling the mode at all.. how to force to load the model?

Comment: Provide any non object value to `transitionTo` argument, like `this.transitionTo('cs2i.balance.balanceReview', modelId)`

Comment: can you please help me to showing a direction by answering this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45735227/cp-validaiton-always-returns-true-when-validate-from-router

Comment: Sorry.I haven't used this addon.